# fdisk hangs on "Syncing disk" when resizing a raw QEMU image

Tags: fdisk, qemu

I'm using fdisk to resize the partitions on a raw QEMU image. When I write the new partition table, it hangs at "Syncing disks."

Note that I'm running fdisk as non-root since I don't need root to edit the image file.

What would cause "Syncing disks" to hang like this?

Comment: Run `strace -o fdisk.strace fdisk` to see what it's hanging on.

Comment: It's dead now... I tried strace -p to attach to the process, but it hung, and I couldn't kill it either!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After printing the "Syncing disk" message, fdisk calls sync(2) syscall, which causes all buffered modifications to file metadata and data to be written to the underlying file systems. It is expected that this operation can take some time, but it shouldn't hang forever. If it does, you might see in which function in the kernel it hangs in /proc/FDISK_PID/stack.

The question is why fdisk calls sync() while working with the image file (not real device). It should not be needed IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Possible workaround:
I had the same problem, and the way around it was to use `sfdisk` instead of `fdisk`. You will find that you can do anything with sfdisk fdisk can do.

For example, instead of doing:

```
  fdisk $image <<FDISK
p
d
$partition
n
p
$partition
$start
p
w
FDISK
```

I did:

```
echo ",+," | sfdisk -N2 $image
```

Suddenly no sync problems.